# Name of a class representing a 3d model

Tags: naming

How would you name a class describing a 3d model?

- `3DModel`, this is not a valid identifier
- `ThreeDimensionalModel` I do not like this
- `Model` to general
- `AnimatedMesh` to technical or close to implementation, but maybe ok if there are accessors for face and vertex arrays. But the model is more than the mesh, as it also contains UV vertices used for shading.
- `Animated3dShape` But the model is more than the mesh, as it also contains UV vertices used for shading.

Comment: Can you give some more information on why you think this matters? If I have a person class, do I have to call it something else because it is a clothed person or a person carrying a hammer?

Comment: The problem with "Model" is that it very context dependent. A person is  a person. A Model is any representation of whatever it is a model of: It can be a system of equations, a miniaturized train/railway, something made out of clay... And using a namespace does not help with context, as the naming problem moves to the namespace.

Comment: I like `AnimatedMesh` and `Animated3dShape`.   The name doesn't have to embody every possible characteristic; that's what methods and properties are for.  The name only has to be sufficiently descriptive of what the object is.

Comment: What about Model3d?

Comment: I'd try _3DModel

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the argument against using just 'Model' in a namespace. A Rendering::Model is different to a Math::Model is different to a FashionShow::Model.

Comment: @SeanBurton However the "Math::Model" could also be exactly the same thing as the Animated3dShape: https://github.com/milasudril/snowflake-toolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go with `AnimatedPolyhedron`. That tells what it is, and as Robert Harvey commented, texturing aspects does not have to be a part of the class name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a convention of [SubType][Type][Variant].

Leading me to AnimatedModel3d.

That leaves me open to create classes for a non-animated model, and a model that's not even 3d.

I would also consider any broader namespacing in the application, something in the namespace that contains the Type for example would nullify the need for the Model part, and your classes would become Models.Animated3d format.

Here's the catch though.  Do you even NEED all that possible variation?  Could you not simply go with `Model`, because there's no other type of model in your application?

2p.